# Flexible serialization with MultiParamTypeClasses

Tags: haskell, serialization, typeclass, multiparameter

I'm playing around with an idea for an extensible serialization library. I have the following typeclass:

```
class Monoid m => BuilderS m a where
  cstr :: String -> a -> m
```

The idea is that people can define instances for pairs of different serializers/types, like this:

```
import qualified Data.Serialize.Builder as B

instance Serialize a => BuilderS B.Builder a where
  cstr _ = B.fromByteString . encode
```

And a usage example:

```
sfPut :: (BuilderS a b, Monoid a) => WriterT a Identity ()
sfPut = do
  tell $ cstr "version" (5 :: Int)
  -- ...
  return ()
```

However, it turns out that the type of `a` needs to be specialized:

```
Could not deduce (BuilderS a Int) arising from a use of `cstr'
    from the context (BuilderS a b, Monoid a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 sfPut :: (BuilderS a b, Monoid a) => WriterT a Identity ()
```

i.e, the following type signature works without problems:

```
sfPut :: WriterT B.Builder Identity ()
```

Is there an obvious way I'm missing to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I use the typeclass you've given, then use GHCi to check types:

```
> :t tell $ cstr "version" (5 :: Int)
tell $ cstr "version" (5 :: Int) :: (MonadWriter s m, BuilderS s Int) => m ()
```

So it looks like you need to specify that it's `BuilderS a Int`, not `BuilderS a b`.  If I have

```
sfPut :: BuilderS a Int => WriterT a Identity ()
sfPut = tell $ cstr "version" (5 :: Int)
```

It works fine.  Note that you need `FlexibleContexts` for this as well, and the type signature on `5` is not optional.

---

To further elaborate, the type signature you gave `sfPut` was

```
BuilderS m a => WriterT m Identity ()
```

But you had the term `tell $ cstr "version (5 :: Int)`, which has the type

```
BuilderS m Int => WriterT m Identity ()
```

The type system couldn't unify `a` and `Int`, so it gave you an error.  Additionally, if you leave off the type signature from `5 :: Int`, you'd instead have

```
tell $ cstr "version" 5 :: (Num a, BuilderS m a) => WriterT m Identity ()
```

But since `a` doesn't appear in `WriterT m Identity ()`, the type system doesn't know which instance of `Num` to use for `5` and would give you another error.  Specifically, you'd get

```
> let sfPut = tell $ cstr "version" 5
Could not deduce (BuilderS s a0)
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘sfPut’
from the context (BuilderS s a, MonadWriter s m, Num a)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘sfPut’:
             (BuilderS s a, MonadWriter s m, Num a) => m ()
  at <interactive>:20:5-35
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‘sfPut’
  has the inferred type ‘forall (m :: * -> *) s a.
                         (BuilderS s a, MonadWriter s m, Num a) =>
                         m ()’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

However, if you use a monomorphic literal instead (or a value whose type is not polymorphic), then you can easily do

```
> let sfPut = tell $ cstr "version" "I'm not polymorphic"
> :t sfPut
sfPut :: (BuilderS s [Char], MonadWriter s m) => m ()
```

Comment: So, you have to either specify `m` or `a` in `BuilderS`, but there's no way to help the type system infere both?

Comment: @PhilipKamenarsky The problem is that you said it needed to be a `BuilderS m b`, but `cstr "version (5 :: Int)` has type `BuilderS m Int`.  The type signature is required on the `5` (at least in GHC 7.8) because otherwise it can't determine which instance of `Num` to use since the `b` term only appears in the constraints side of the type signature.