# Automatically infer multiparameter instance

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass, multiparameter

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449183/flexible-serialization-with-multiparamtypeclasses), I have the following typeclasses:

```
class Monoid m => BuilderS m a where
  cstr :: String -> a -> m

class SafeCopy a where
  putSafe :: a -> m
```

Providing instances for `BuilderS`:

```
import qualified Data.Serialize.Builder as B

instance Serialize a => BuilderS B.Builder a where
  cstr _ = B.fromByteString . encode

instance BuilderS CustomBuilder Int where
  cstr = ...

instance BuilderS CustomBuilder String where
  cstr = ...

etc.
```

I would like to define instances of `SafeCopy` like this:

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int }

instance SafeCopy Person where
  putSafe p = cstr "name" (name p)
```

However, in this specific case the compiler can't find an instance of `BuilderS m String`. I've tried several things:

- Add all primitive datatypes to the constraints of `putSafe`:
  `putSafe :: (BuilderS m Int, BuilderS m String, ...) => a -> m`. This works, but is not extensible (i.e. what if I want to have a `BuilderS m Vector` constraint in the future?)
- Add `m` to the type parameters of `SafeCopy`.
- Use a custom sum type: `data SumT m = forall a b. (BuilderS m a, BuilderS m b) => a :+: b` and then have `putSafe :: a -> SumT m`.

Still, I'm not providing enough information to the type system so it can defer the decision of which exact instance of `BuilderS` to use for later. What am I missing?

Comment: What was the problem with (2) [add m to type parameters] ?

Comment: `m` from both cases are independent. In second case, `m` is a free parameter. So, you should write manually final type, `putSafe p = cstr "name" (name p) :: CustomBuilder String`

Comment: Your type for `putSafe` promises to be able to return any type the caller wants.  Clearly this isn't possible.

Comment: @augustss: Yes, but what can be done (i.e. what constraints/types/etc can be added) so that the type system can figure out which instance of `BuilderS` to use when `putSafe` is evaluated?

Comment: @bennofs: When I add `m` to `SafeCopy` and try to define an instance `SafeCopy Person m` the same error occurs. I would like to be able to define *one* instance of `SafeCopy` for *all* instances of `BuilderS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class SafeCopy a m where
  putSafe :: a -> m

instance BuilderS m String => SafeCopy Person m where
  putSafe p = cstr "name" (name p)
```

You'll need to turn on a lot of language extensions.